# App Icon Not replaced in Android Application Manager

Tags: android

I have created an android project, first time I have run this, app icon is fine in application manager. Then I have replaced a new icon (same name) in the project. But when running the app icon not gets replaced. Even I removed the app, install it again. Any solution to this?

Regards

Comment: are you sure you replaced all `ic_launcher`s in every drawable folder. i.e. mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi..etc?

Comment: yes I did. I cleaned up, build and then it works.

Comment: I just figured out that if you don't put your icons in mipmap and leave them in drawable, then the launcher icon will not get replaced and it will use existing one if it has one. (Even if you uninstall/re-install app!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are "absoulutely" sure that you have changed all icons in all drawable folders (hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,etc), do following steps:

Step 1: Uninstall the application from the device.

Step 2: Refresh the Project in Eclipse (F5 or Right Click - Refresh)

Step 3: From Eclipse menu, Project - Check "Build Automatically"

Step 4: From Eclipse menu, Project - Clean - Clean Projects Selected Below

Step 5: Run the Application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to re-build your apk after cleaning the project if you are working in eclipse and "Build automatically" is not ticked in "Project" menu